# using google.loader.ClientLocation

Tags: jquery, google-api

what will be best way to use

```
        using google.loader.ClientLocation
```

to get client country & city name in jquery

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does jQuery get involved in this?  If you are using the Google Ajax API you can access these properties as explained [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation).